# Can :var NAME=ASSIGN in org mode work if ASSIGN includes a colon?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, org-ref

I use org-ref in org-mode to handle cross references, and I use labels like tab:one, fig:two, etc., to identify label types and format them accordingly (using cleveref in LaTeX export). I then have source blocks that take input from tables using the `:var NAME=ASSIGN` mechanism. It looks like org-mode always interprets a colon in ASSIGN as a filename (this is what the manual says) and so it cannot find the reference. I have tried escaping in various ways but I have found no solution. For example, none of these work:

```
| x |
|---|
| 1 |

# reference not found
#+begin_src R :var data=tab:one
  data$x
#+end_src

# reference not found
#+begin_src R :var data=tab\:one
  data$x
#+end_src

# assigns the string "tab:one", not table content
#+begin_src R :var data="tab:one"
  data$x
#+end_src

# same as above
#+begin_src R :var data='tab:one'
  data$x
#+end_src
```

Is there a way to make this work? I guess it may be possible to reconfigure org-ref to use a different delimiter, but I would prefer keeping the standard setting.